# Find the largest domain on which the following functions are defined

Tags: real-analysis

Find the largest domain on which the following functions are defined?

(i) $ \ f(x,y)=e^{xy}(xy+8x+y^3) \ $ and   (ii)  $ \ f(x,y)=\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2} \ $

Explain why the functions are continuous on their doamins.

**Answer:**

(i)

The function $ \ f(x,y)=e^{xy}(xy+8x+y^3) \ $ has domain $ \ (-\infty,\infty) \ $

But how to explain that the function is continuous on the domain $ \ (-\infty,\infty) \ $ ?

(ii)

the function $ \ f(x,y)=\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2} \ $ has doamin $ \ x^2+y^2<1 \ $ i.e. the unit open disc.

But how to explain the continuity here also?

Help me doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The domain of two-variables function is within $\;\Bbb R^2\;$ , not $\;\Bbb R\;$, so in $\;(i)\;$ it must be $\;\Bbb R^2\;$, and $\;(ii)\;$ is *almost* correct: it must be the **closed** disk $\;x^2+y^2\le1\;$

In both cases you have products/composition of continuous functions: exponential, polynomial and/or square root.